# What does it mean for to be a vector space *over* $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$? Are they fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, real-numbers, vector-fields

What does it mean for to be a vector space *over* $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$? Are they fields?

I have a list of subsets (like matrices and linear maps) and am trying to determine if they are vector spaces over R and/or over $\mathbb C$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I know vector spaces need to be subspaces so I have been trying to use the Subspace Test, but I have no idea if that works for both "over $\mathbb R$ and/or over $\mathbb C$"?

Thanks!

Comment: "Are they fields?"  What do you mean by "they"? $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are fields. Vector spaces are not necessarily fields.

Comment: A vector space $V$ is *over* a field $F$ if scalar multiplication can be defined for every scalar in $F$. So for example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, but not over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean for to be a vector space over R or C?

As part of the definition of a vector space, there is a scaling action, that takes a scalar and a vector, and produces a new vector. These scalars most come from somewhere.

This somewhere is a field, and the vector space is said to be a vector space *over that field*. Thus "$V$ is a vector space over $K$" means that $V$ is a vector space that allows scalars from the field $K$.

So the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries and standard addition is easily seen to be a vector space over the real numbers with standard scaling. But it is not a vector space over the complex numbers with standard scaling, as for instance, the identity matrix scaled by $i$ doesn't have real entries.

In contrast, the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with complex entries (and the standard operations) is both a vector space (of dimension 8) over the real numbers and a vector space (of dimension 4) over the complex numbers. In fact, any vector space over $\Bbb C$ automatically becomes a vector space over $\Bbb R$ with double the dimension in a very natural way.